# How do we learn BPM products?

Tags: bpm, bpmn

What are the topics I should learn for a BPM (Business Process Management) product? I mean, do I need to learn BPMN (Business Process Modelling Notation), BPEL (Business Process Excecution Language)? Are there any open source lightweight BPM products by Apache or somebody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are implementing a BPM product, you should know a business process modelling spec like BPMN and an execution language like BPEL and BPML.

Otherwise, if you're looking for application development using a BPM Product, you don't need to know those specs.

Some open source BPM suites to explore and use,

- [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/)
- [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm)
- [Intalio](http://www.intalio.com/)

Comment: AFAIK Activiti is not an Apache project, it merily uses the Apache license.

Comment: Dhanunjai, Thank you for your kind answer. I understood. But Why do we use the IBM process server? is that one related to BPM?

Comment: I want to persue my career in BPM platform. thats why i am trying to understand on how and what topics i should learn for a BPM product.